# Mac app will no longer open

Tags: applications, high-sierra

I have an app installed on my iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6. Normally I would just double-click on this app in the Applications folder and the app would start right up. Recently it stopped doing that. When I double-click on the app nothing happens. If I right click on the app and chose open, nothing happens.  Does anyone know why double-clicking doesn't work anymore?

When I show package contents and go to MacOs i can open the run.sh file. The contents are:
`#!/bin/sh
source "/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/py34"/bin/activate root
"/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/py34"/bin/anaconda-navigator $@`

Comment: When you db click on application a "ghost" like transparent image of the application icon floats up that indicates it's starting up. Does this occur with yours? Does it show in your dock as open?

Comment: Hi @JBis, it's me again. No, it doesn't, and if I click the icon in the dock it rises up once and then stops.

Comment: Do this: right click on the application>show package contents>contents>macOS>double click that file. This will open a terminal window. Copy and pages everything in that window and edit your question.

Comment: Please if your question is about Anaconda3 and not any application on MacOS X, say so in the title and content of your question. Otherwise you risk to get to broad answers, as “debug the application”.

Comment: It'snot anaconda3, its the Mac app Anaconda-Navigator.  I guess it's like any other Mac app except it won't open when double-clicked.  Thank you for your input but I don't understand what you mean. I thought I expressed the question pretty clearly and received a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that something in the .app package was damaged or corrupted over time. It will be difficult to tell. If you have a Time Machine backup you can try restoring the earliest copy of that app that you have.

You can open up Console.app and look through the logs and see if there is anything about that specific app in any of the myriad log that macOS keeps. That may at least give you more info why it is not launching.

If it is an app store app, re-download it. If it is unavailable perhaps there is a file inside the app package that indicates who the developer is.

If it wasn't an App Store app I would go looking for it online. Often you can find older copies of an app online line.

Comment: I went back a few weeks and extracted the app from Time Machine. It works fine now.  Thanks for the suggestion. I think I would have eventually gotten there but you suggestion spurred me on! lol